# Finding out who are the users who liked my page on Facebook Like button?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is there a way to find out who the users (who likes my page) are on Facebook?

I've looked through Graph API and got totally lost:
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Eventually I'd like to be able to pick one user from all those who liked my page and Send A Message to the user to let him/her know that he/she won!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to send messages to users through the facebook api anymore as in the past it was abused.

Comment: I understand that. I will actually manually alert the user. But is it possible to get a list of all the users who clicked the like button?

Comment: it doesn't look like it's possible to do through the API. See the list of possible connections for page: `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page`. There is no connection to get the list of users who liked it. But if you are going to do it manually anyway, why not just use the facebook web interface (manually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went for a hybrid solution:

- http://www.askdavetaylor.com/make_create_like_button_facebook_fan_page.html

Thanks Ben Lee.